# What is the symbol on Boruto's right hand?

Tags: boruto

In Episode 66 of *Boruto*, there is a symbol that appears on Boruto's right hand.

What is it? Is it a curse mark or sealing jutsu? What does it represent?

[image: Boruto episode 66]

Comment: Related: [Does Naruto know that Boruto has a curse mark on his hand?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/54178/does-naruto-know-that-boruto-has-a-curse-mark-on-his-hand?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol on Boruto's hand is known as a [Kāma](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/K%C4%81ma).

> Kāma is a seal that takes the shape of a black diamond on the user's palm

[Boruto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki) received the Kāma after he defeated Momoshiki. With this, Boruto is able to absorb different techniques

> After defeating Momoshiki, Boruto received a seal on his right hand in the shape of a diamond, with which Boruto can absorb other techniques, like fūinjutsu and nature transformation

Comment: in the manga, they call it KARMA. I think karma in cooler if the context is built around it well enough.

Answer (score 2):

The mark indicates that pure otsutsuki chakra is flowing inside of Boruto, during Shippuden when the sage of six paths gave naruto and sasuke chakra you could see the marks on their palms. This is basically the same thing but instead boruto has permanent Otsutsuki chakra due to his Jougan :)