# Does Naruto know that Boruto has a curse mark on his hand?

Tags: boruto

As the title said, does Naruto know that there is a curse mark on Boruto's hand after the battle against Momoshiki Otsutsuki?

> *Any spoiler is allowed but remember put a spoiler tag.

[image]

Comment: No only sasuke knows about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Naruto does know that Boruto has the [Kāma](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/K%C4%81ma) seal.

> Naruto at this point **definitely knows about the Karma mark on Boruto.** He also knows it is on Kawaki and has them train together causing their marks to resonate with each other in an attempt to learn more about it. <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

This point is also proven respectively in the manga, during Naruto and Boruto's Shinobi Hand-to-Hand Combat:

> [image]

Considering Boruto using it right in front of Naruto, as well as him being able to identify it's name, he obviously knows Boruto has it.

[Source](https://www.quora.com/How-would-Naruto-react-if-he-found-out-about-Boruto-s-Karma-mark-and-Jougan)